# Import from Redis "No module named 'redis.commands'"

Tags: python, redis

I have two imports

```
import redis
from redis.commands.json.path import Path
```

redis is installed, however I'm getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis.commands'
```

Any solution for that?

Comment: What version of the package are you using ? Should be > v4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install redis correctly:

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade redis
```

If you are using conda:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge redis-py
```

Then try:

```py
import redis
from redis.commands.json.path import Path
# ...
```

See the [redis-py documentation](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/search_json_examples.html?highlight=path#Projecting-using-JSON-Path-expressions) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have an older version of the Redis libraries. Try:

```
pip install --upgrade redis
```